# How to pull images from the DOM in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

If you have looked at Pinterest you will know they have a bookmarklet that the user can press and it loads up more javascript which gathers certain images from the DOM and lets them pin them at the site. I found the gathering images interesting and would like to be able to do that. Where would I be able to look to learn how to gather images from the DOM so that I could let the user do stuff with them? I have done google searches but most are about scraping with php and that doesn't really work if the user is on a page that requires login, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Am not very sure what you are asking but here is how you get an image using javascript:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

This will return a nodeList which you can loop through to work on a single image at a time

```
for (var i=0,l=images.length;i<l;i++){
   // your code here
   console.log(images[i].src);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if I'm not supposed to ask another question here but I only ask because it is directly relevant. What if there is no img tag? For instance, today's google image is <div id="hplogo-o" style="background:url(/logos/2012/valentines12-hp-h.png)

Comment: @townie if there is not `img` tag then you have to take css style of each structure and check the properties where that image could be for `url(..)` string

Answer (score 0):

it is actually quite simple using jquery http://jquery.com/

you can do a simple selector like `$('img')` .. which will give you a collection of all the images on a page ... from that you can get the source of any of them using `$('img').first().attr('src')` <=== this will return the source of the first image on the page

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Create a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). To get all the images on the page do something like this:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var imageSrc = images[i].src;
    // Do something with the image
    // ie, add it to the DOM and let them select one.
    // It also might be worth looking at the offsetWidth property to only grab larger images
}
```

Here's the [source to the Pinterest bookmarklet](http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js) for reference